# I want build AEM Project with maven i'm getting a error

Tags: maven-2, aem, aem-6

I was trying to build a aem project with
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=12 -DarchetypeCatalog=https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/
this code but I'm getting the  error as Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.adobe.granite.archetypes:aem-project-archetype:12) -> [Help 1]
I tried reinstalling maven but still I'm getting a same error.

Comment: Your version is pretty much old, try to use some newer version, like latest one, which is 27.
https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype

Answer (score 1):

The archetype command is incorrect. Use this command to generate project:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
 -D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem \
 -D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype \
 -D aemVersion=6.5.5 \
 -D frontendModule=none \
 -D includeDispatcherConfig=n \
 -D archetypeVersion=25 \
 -D appTitle="My Site" \
 -D appId="mysite" \
 -D groupId="com.mysite" \
```

One more point, a default adobe-public profile is preferable for AEM projects. Make sure to include [this settings.xml](https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/experience-manager/kb/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository/jcr_content/main-pars/download_section/download-1/settings_xml.zip) into /Users/*user*/.m2 directory. Refer to [adobe documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/archetype/overview.html?lang=en#system-requirements) for best practices and archetype compatible versions.